# Задача на рекурсивную последовательность С++

Tags: c++, математика, рекурсия

> Доказать, что рекурсивная последовательность (изображение) имеет
> предел при n→∞ и найти значение этого предела. Определить глубину
> рекурсии во время расчета.
> Я не могу понять как найти значение предела, помогите пожалуйста.

[image: изображение]

> Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int depth=0;

double R1(double n)
{

    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        depth++;
        return 2 * R1(n - 1);
}

double R2(double n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 8 / (R2(n - 1) * R2(n - 1));
}

double R3(double n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (R1(n) + R2(n)) / 3;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да предел-то найти несложно, он равен 2.

Просто если предел есть, то, подставив предельное значение справа, мы получим его и слева...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решая это уравнение относительно *a*, находим, что *a*=2...

Ну, а глубину рекурсии, раз не задана точность счета, можно оценить так:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int n = 0;
    double a = 1;
    for(double b = 0; abs(a-b) > 0; n++)
    {
        b = a;
        a = (2*a+8/a/a)/3;
    }
    cout << "n = " << n << endl;
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
}
```

Результат расчета смотрите здесь: https://ideone.com/C2bFPQ

Ну, а доказывать, что предел существует, можно с помощью [теоремы Банаха](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид принятого ответа (птичка слева). Жаль, что вы не прочли даже первую страницу сайта, кстати...